# .htaccess and gzip compression

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, compression, gzip

i have question about GZIP compression,
actualy my wordpress website doesn't have .htaccess to be able to use that feature, so can i create .htaccess file only for gzip, it won't change anything on website?

Comment: Please note there is a dedicated site for wordpress on SE - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add it to the existing .htaccess file your Wordpress creates for SE friendly URLs. If you don't have an htaccess file from Wordpress then you can create your own with the GZIP code in it and it won't break Wordpress at all.